# Как низкоуровневый код использующий стек узнает откуда он начинается?

Tags: linux, unix, процесс

Когда операционная система запускает процесс, она выделяет ему память под стек, но как низкоуровневый код узнает начальный адрес стека?

[image: классическая схема адресного пространства процесса]

Если взять за основу эту схему, то становится понятно, как код процесса может узнать адреса текста, инициализированных данных, неинициализированных данных и кучи (просто прибавлять кол-во выделенной с помощью системных вызовов памяти к концу BSS). Однако, не ясно, как становится известен адрес стека и аргументов командной строки.

Если немного пораскинуть мозгами, то самый логичный ответ на этот вопрос - при запуске процесса ОС сама настраивает (думаю, что в данном примере не важно какая именно ОС, но я отталкиваю от примера linux) регистры стека на нужные значения, однако у меня нет опыта программирования на ассемблере (только теория), а все источники, которые я читал явно на это не указывают, поэтому я не могу быть уверен в этом предположении. Ну и если следовать этому предположению, то и адреса аргументов командной строки можно узнать отсчитав их от адреса стека.

Если все мои догадки верны, то хотелось бы получить утвердительный ответ от точно знающих это людей, если же используется другой способ, то хотелось бы получить подробное его описание.

Comment: Просто перед самым запуском процесса ОС выставляет нужное значение регистра ESP / RSP. То есть ответ - да.

Comment: Да, уже первая команда прикладной программы, находящаяся по адресу  `_start` (см. вывод `nm`, `objdump`) работает с настроенным SP. Другой вопрос, откуда какая ОС берет это начальное значение (и размер стека). В Baremetal мы обычно берем это из символов, определенных в linker-script (но в Linux я похожих символов в elf не увидел)

Comment: Есть статья со ссылками на конкретные куски кода ядра: https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/

Comment: @avp, так потому что вы не туда смотрите, и, наверное, не совсем знаете, как загружается ядро. Начните, например, с *header.S* (подразумевается x86).

Comment: @0andriy, раз уж разбирались с x86, так и написали бы ответ (заодно с ТС кто-нибудь еще просветится), исходя из каких настроек Linux случайно выбирает из заданного диапазона виртуальный адрес дна  стека пользовательского процесса

Comment: В ELF файле есть секция `stack`, которая считывается загрузчиком при загрузке программы в процесс